# How to colorize expression without its boundary in shell script

Tags: regex, bash, shell, colors, grep

Having an input such as:

```
./Tomcatv8.1/projects.xml:  <jdbc url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=MMMABC" />
./Tomcatv8.2/projects.xml:  <jdbc url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=MMMABC_New" />
./Tomcatv8.3/projects.xml:  <jdbc url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=ABC_20170407_STG" />
./Tomcatv8.5/projects.xml:  <jdbc url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=UPGABC_New" />
```

I want to colorize the database name.

I used

```
grep --color=auto -E "[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\""
```

It works quite well, except that it also highlight the final " sign, which is used as a boundary in my regexp.

How to just highlight the database name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may enclose the `"` into a lookahead and use a PCRE regex with `grep`:

```
grep --color=auto -P "[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(?=\")"
                   ^               ^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/umTr17/1)

The `(?=\")` only checks if the text matches the pattern, but the value is not added to the resulting match. See more about [lookarounds in regex here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).